# How do i edit rule with cssutils in python

Tags: python, css, edit, rules

I have never used cssutils in python. when I print a rule I get the following string, how do I edit the css rule in python? For example if I wanted to change the background color?

```
<cssutils.css.CSSStyleRule object selectorText='#panel' style='color: #eee;\nbackground-color: #000;\nfont-weight: bold;\nheight: 32px' _namespaces={} at 0x7f9b5d76bd30>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit rule simply by changing `rule.style` attribute

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cssutils

stylesheet = cssutils.parseString(style)

for rule in stylesheet.cssRules:
    if rule.type == cssutils.css.CSSRule.STYLE_RULE:
        rule.style.background = "#abcdef"
```

`rule.style` is instance of `cssutils.css.CSSStyleDeclaration` class. More info in [cssutils docs](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/docs/css.html#cssstyledeclaration).